# RedirectMatch vs. Deny from All - Which is more secure?

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess

I'm currently working on an app with a lot of directories under the public webroot that should not be accessible publicly. Currently this is done by dropping a buckload of .htaccess files with `Deny from All` rules in all of the directories that shouldn't be browsable.

Recently however I discovered that by defining a list of RedirectMatch rules in the .htaccess in the root would also "hide" these files throwing a 404 like this:

```
RedirectMatch 404 "/uploads*"
RedirectMatch 404 "/keys*"
RedirectMatch 404 "/private_files*"
....
```

Does the RedirectMatch method impose any other security vulnerabilities which would advise against switching to such a "centrally managed" system for defining what is public and what not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent. The [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive works at URL level. That means that `RedirectMatch 404 "/keys*"` can prevent you from accesing any URL that starts with `/keys` while the other method will only affect those specific physical directories (no matter their URL). It can be a bug or a feature.

Also, if you are concerned about performance, Apache will need to parse `RedirectMatch` rules in the main `.htaccess` for every single request received by the server. Considering that attempts to load those directories are expected to be pretty uncommon, it's possibly an unnecessary overhead.

(As someone else will probably point out, the most secure mechanism is to move those files *outside* the public document root, but I understand that some hosting providers do not allow so.)

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer i have been looking for. The overhead is indeed collateral damage which could easily be avoided. I'm sticking with the separate .htaccess files. Moving it out of the webroot is my first choice too but indeed the host doesn't allow it hence i'm looking for another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /uploads>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: That's a nice solution too, unfortunately i don't have access to the vhost config so this is a no go either. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisR: You can do this in `.htaccess`, no need to have access to vhost! :)

Comment: From what i tried in the past and what the Apache docs say .htaccess isn't in the context that allows <directory>. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory